# PrimeNG V15 exit edit mode of a CellEditing table

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable, tablecelleditor

I have a PrimeNG table

```
<p-table [value]="products" dataKey="name" (onEditInit)="onEditInit($event)"   (onEditComplete)="onEditComplete($event)"   (onEditCancel)="onEditCancel($event)"
>
```

and I am using the CellEdiding Function

```
<tr>
      <td
        [pEditableColumn]="product.name"
        [pEditableColumnField]="product.comment"
        [pEditableColumnRowIndex]="product.id"
      >
```

I can exit from the editing mode by typing "enter" or "escape" on the keyboard.
Is there any way to do it by clicking on a button ?

Exemple available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableedit-demo-j3titj?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

See : [Switch p-table cell programmatically to edit mode in Primeng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304095/switch-p-table-cell-programmatically-to-edit-mode-in-primeng/63002544#63002544)

and use :

```
setTimeout(() => {
     this.editableColumn.closeEditingCell();
}, 0);
```